# Scala erasure class type parameter

Tags: scala, type-parameter, erasure

I have the following setup:

```
class Test[A](function: A => String) {
   def process(data: Any) {         //has to be Any since it is user IO
      if (data of Type A) 
          function(data)
   }
}
```

I cant seem to get the the typecheck to work.
I tried adding an implicit TypeTag to Test[A] but I could not access it from within proccess.
Is it possible to match against the type parameter of Test within the process function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ClassTag` and `match` for that purpose:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Test[A : ClassTag](function: A => String) {
  def process(data: Any) { //has to be Any since it is user IO 
    data match {
      case data: A => function(data)
      case _       =>
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to the implicit `ClassTag` in scope, the `match` can discriminate `A` even though it is generic.

Comment: very nice! I was very close :-) but not quite

Comment: Actually it does not work. It compiles without warning but during runtime case data: A matches anything

Answer (score 0):

using [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
  class Test[A: Typeable](function: A => String){
    import shapeless.syntax.typeable._
    def process(data: Any) {         //has to be Any since it is user IO
      data.cast[A] map { function(_) }
    }
  }
```

This one is safe, in that it returns an Option[A], so when the cast fails, you can pattern match on the None.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Is there anything in the standard library which can achieve the same thing?

Comment: the "standard library" (`data.isInstanceOf[A]` and `data.asInstanceOf[A]`) only work partially - up to erasure. So you won't be able to match `List[Int]` vs `List[String]`, it will just be a `List[_]`, possibly leading to false positives of `instanceOf` and `ClassCastException` thrown at runtime.

Comment: With the newer scala versions you can use TypeTags which capture the full type: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `data` has to be of type `Any` (wouldn't user input be of type `String`?), but if it truly does, then it probably reflects a situation where the type cannot be anticipated at compile time.  In such a case, you probably want the method to throw a run-time error when trying to cast:

```
class Test[A](function: A => String) {
   def process(data: Any) = {
      function(data.asInstanceOf[A]) //might throw an error
   }
}
```

Or possibly use the `Try` monad:

```
class Test[A](function: A => String) {
   def process(data: Any) = {
      Try(function(data.asInstanceOf[A]))
   }
}
```

Of course what is most preferable would be to know the type of `data` at compile time:

```
class Test[A](function: A => String) {
   def process(data: A) = {
      function(data)
   }
}
```